# Reclassify Raster array using new values from a list array - shape mismatch error

Tags: geotiff-tiff, rasterio, numpy

I am trying to reclassify some raster values using new values stored in an array. Below is my code:

```py
import rasterio
import numpy as np

# path to the raster data
in_img = "...\raster.tif"

# Open a raster data and read
ds = rasterio.open(in_img)
data = ds.read()
print(data)

#result

[[-9999 -9999 -9999 ... -9999 -9999 -9999]

 [-9999 -9999 -9999 ... -9999 -9999 -9999]

 [-9999 -9999 -9999 ... -9999 -9999 -9999]

 ...

 [-9999 -9999 -9999 ... -9999 -9999 -9999]

 [-9999 -9999 -9999 ... -9999 -9999 -9999]

 [-9999 -9999 -9999 ... -9999 -9999 -9999]]

# reclass table array

b = np.array(reclasstable)

b

#result listed as: id, original value, new value

array([[   1,    1,    1],       

       [   6,    6,    1],

       [   7,    7,    1],

       [   8,   11,    2],       

       [  12,   21,    1]])

#reclass raster

dims=b.shape

#rows,columns

for x in range(dims[1]):

    data[np.where(data=b[2])]=b[3]

#also tried this line

    data[data==b[2]]=b[3]

print(data)


#Error message

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (0,1,59550,89200)
```

How do I go about solving the above -- trying to reclass values in the raster that matches values in the original column of table array to values in the new column of the table array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the rows of your (re-)classification rules array.

```py
import numpy as np
reclass_table = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,5,6]])
for row in reclass_table:
   _, p, q = row
   data[data == p] = q
```

I'd also be tempted to store that in something that is not also an array; a simple list of lists would suffice:

```py
reclass_table = [[1,2,3],[2,5,6]]
for rule in reclass_table:
   _, p, q = rule
   data[data == p] = q
```

Or if the rules are more sophisitcated, a dictionary that labels it conceptually and makes it easier to comprehend and extend:

```py
reclassification_rules = {
    'One rule': {'mask': lambda a: a == 2, 'value': 3},
    'Another rule': {'mask': lambda a: a == 3, 'value': 4},
}
for label, rule in reclassification_rules.items():
    mask = rule['mask'](data)
    data[mask] = rule['value']
```

Just be careful about the order of your rules as these will mutate `data` as the rules are evaluated in order. (Latter rules can affect the values that are outcomes of earier rules.) Consider the outcome of `One rule` and how `Another rule` will actually ultimately reclassify values of 2 as 4, even though that is not the apparent intention of `Another rule`.

Comment: Useful answers that worked fine. I forgot to mention in my question that I specifically wanted to read new values from a table so I could change them as needed and script would still work fine. I went with the second suggested answer and replaced the first line with `reclass_table = (table)` and it works. Thanks!